# how to extract geometry from source file in the form of XYZ coordinate

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge

I use the link reference:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/xtract-geometry-from-source-file/

but at the end of task when I send request

```
curl  -X GET \
  'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/URL_SAFE_URN_OF_SOURCE_FILE/manifest' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'
```

it shows only .png URN not .obj UNR like below

```
"urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:URL_SAFE_URN_OF_SOURCE_FILE/output/geometry/b576231b-9684-3609-8fa0-1221a424a77c.obj"
```

how I get .obj file.

Comment: Could you provide the full manifest? (you can delete the URN parts if you want)

Comment: yes ,thank you for response

Comment: Could you please add it to the original question above?